# Deja Dup Backup Tool - When does automatic backup occur

Tags: backup, deja-dup

**Specs:**

- deja-dup 30.0-0ubuntu4.1
- Elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya (64-bit)
- Ubuntu 14.04

I came across [this](https://www.lifewire.com/backup-ubuntu-4126286) page, explaining how to use the Deja Dup Backup Tool, and it looks exactly like the tool I need. Problem is, there's no way to tell when (which time of day, and day of week) the backup process will occur, and I can't find anything online about it either.

I've set the "Automatic Scheduling" toggle to `On`, selected "Every `Week`" and "Keep `Forever`", but now I'm worried that it's gonna start doing backups while I'm busy working, and slow down my PC.

**Question:** Is there some way to set the time of day and day of week that backups occur? If not, when does backups occur, and if it occurs while I'm working, will it slow down my PC?

**A quick follow-up question:** Every time it does a back-up, is it going to delete the previous back-up, or does it compare the current backup to the previous one and only update any new changes? Or, does it create a new (potentially enormous) backup file every time?

Here's a screenshot of the Scheduling tab, in case it helps:

[image]

Comment: I had the same concerns, so I just do the backups manually.  For the second part of your question, after it does a full backup, it does incremental backups (only the changes) for ~ three months, then it does another full backup.  It tries to keep two full backup chains around, but it may keep more if you have lots of disk space.  It will eventually start deleting old backups.  Its ways are mysterious and not transparent, but it has worked well for me.

Comment: On all the machines I have an automatic weekly backup scheduled, It will make the backup at around 2  in the morning on Thursdays. If the machine is not running at that time, it will make the backup shortly after reboot.

Comment: I use `Timeshift` for system/OS level backups, and `Backups` (Deja Dup) for specific folders in /home (not all of /home). `Macrium Reflect` for disk level backups. Operation, even if the system is being used, is minimal. There is no way to set day/time of backups. Backups are only limited by the storage available in the destination. Fulls, followed by incrementals, is how it optimizes the use of storage. If you use an external location to save backups, backup files will be stored at the top directory level, not in subfolders.